# UTF Encoding Error on Web Page with French Language

Tags: html, node.js, utf-8

I am working on a NodeJS Web App. I have 5 different home page for 5 Language. All other Language (including Japanese, Chinese, Korean) is working as butter, but one with French shows broken characters, like the one shown in image.[image]

I have already tried adding

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

And even this

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-5">
```

And

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

I am not able to solve it with any of this. What might be the case? I don't have any errors on Inspector console.

Data on the page is not pulled from any other API, but the page is a plain html page, where the same text is written like this

> Les véhicules autonomes utilisent énormément de moyens techniques sans
>   fil pour assurer la communication entre un véhicule et un autre, pour
>   transmettre des informations relatives à la circulation routière ou
>   encore pour mettre à jour leur GPS. Les constructeurs automobiles se
>   doivent ...

Comment: if you copy the text and paste in ``.htm`` file and it works fine (local), then it have to do with how your server is serving the file

Comment: The [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) has information about how to properly ask about encoding problems. We can't know what's in the file unless you manage to communicate it unambiguously (a hex dump of a few choice words should suffice).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by changing the Encoding for the File itself. It was encoded ANSI.

I was using Visual Studio for as Code Editor and to save a file with UTF-8 Encoding, I followed these steps.

1. Goto *File*
2. Choose *Save  as*
3. On the Save windows, click on the drop-down attached to Save button, and select *Save with Encoding*
4. Selected UTF-8 with Signature.

Thanks everyone for your time and effort.

Answer (score -2):

You should try this one : "ISO-8859-15".
It works for me.

Comment: It completely depends on the *actual* encoding of the file, which we have no way to know unless you show it in your question.